No mouse events on canvas when using custom Google Maps type
I'm using a Custom Map Type to draw a canvas for each map tile. Once the tiles are loaded, I draw on those canvases based on the the tile and pixel position within the tile. I'm trying to add an addEventListener to detect mouse movement on the respective tiles. However, I'm not getting any mouse events as the Google Maps layer is handling those.
To get these mouse events, I believe I have to use a custom overlay and add the canvas element to the overlayMouseTarget via the onAdd() function.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to implement that within the custom map type I have. Here's a function that illustrates what I'm currently working with. In this case, the canvas event listener never fires.
Where and how would I implement a per tile custom overlay here that would allow me to capture mouse events on the canvas element?
async function drawTest() {
    await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 7,
      minZoom: 3,
      center: {lat: 38, lng: -5}
    });

    function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
      this.tileSize = tileSize;
    }

    CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(tile, zoom, ownerDocument) {
      const canvas = ownerDocument.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.id = "canvas_" + tile.x + "," + tile.y;
      canvas.width = 256;
      canvas.height = 256;
      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });

      // Adding the overlay code here results in mouse events.
      // But the canvases appended to the center of the map.

      return canvas;
    };
    
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));

    let positions = [
      {tileX: 61, tileY: 48, pX: 100, pY: 200},
      {tileX: 62, tileY: 49, pX: 231, pY: 180},
    ]

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_" + positions[i].tileX + "," + positions[i].tileY);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(positions[i].pX, positions[i].pY, 10, 10);
      }
    });
}
drawTest();

Thus far, I've tried implementing the following to getTile() as well as later after the tilesloaded listener occurs. This ends up appending all the canvases to a div in the center which offsets the canvas locations resulting in incorrect placement of the canvas drawings.
var CanvasOverlay = function() {};
CanvasOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CanvasOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {   
  console.log(tile)         
  let panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(canvas);
};
var canvasOverlay = new CanvasOverlay();
canvasOverlay.setMap(map);

Here is a JSFiddle in case it helps visualize the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/stjx1dkm/16/

this might be of interest

Thanks for the comment, Professor Abronsius. Those posts and a good night's sleep got me to what I needed.
Here's how I used a combination of a custom overlay and custom map type to generate per-tile overlays that can see mouse events. Of note, is the getTileBounds function that defines the southwest and northeast corners of the tile in latitude and longitude. Those corners are used as bounds to the overlay. There is guidance within the API documentation to help create your own function, but I found this answer from Dr.Molle to be more helpful.
async function drawTest() {
    await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

    class MyOverlay extends google.maps.OverlayView {
        bounds;
        div;
        canvas;
        constructor(bounds, canvas) {
          super();
          this.bounds = bounds;
          this.canvas = canvas;
        }
    
        onAdd() {
            this.div = document.createElement("div");
            this.div.id = "overlayMouseTarget";
            this.div.style.borderStyle = "none";
            this.div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
            this.div.style.position = "absolute";

            this.div.appendChild(this.canvas);
    
            const panes = this.getPanes();
            panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.div);
        }
    
        draw() {
            const overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
            const sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds.sw);
            const ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds.ne);
    
            if (this.div) {
                this.div.style.left = sw.x + "px";
                this.div.style.top = ne.y + "px";
                this.div.style.width = ne.x - sw.x + "px";
                this.div.style.height = sw.y - ne.y + "px";
            }
        }
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 7,
        minZoom: 3,
        center: {lat: 38, lng: -5}
    });

    function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
    }

    CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(tile, zoom, ownerDocument) {

        const bounds = getTileBounds(tile, 256, zoom);

        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = "canvas_" + tile.x + "," + tile.y;
        canvas.width = 256;
        canvas.height = 256;
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });

        var canvasOverlay = new MyOverlay(bounds, canvas);
        canvasOverlay.setMap(map);

        return canvas;
    };
    
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));

    let positions = [
        {tileX: 61, tileY: 48, pX:100, pY: 200},
        {tileX: 62, tileY: 49, pX:231, pY: 180},
    ]

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_" + positions[i].tileX + "," + positions[i].tileY);
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillRect(positions[i].pX, positions[i].pY, 10, 10);
        }
    });
}

